# I have a picture that when I drag it to the red circle it copies. I want it so it stays where it is copied, not snap to the upper-left corner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a picture that when I drag it to the red circle it copies. I want it so it stays where it is copied, not snap to the upper-left corner. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<span class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
<br />
<div id="picture" ondrop="drop(event)">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
   display: block;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
   nodeCopy.id = "newId";
   ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

Or see a TryIt here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?Filename=GBY2BVYBXUPW

Comment: Please add a better header to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The events have variables you can use.

In this example im using x and y and im positioning the image with absolute position with this line of code

```
 nodeCopy.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; left:"+ ev.x +"px;top:"+ ev.y+"px");
```

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data);
  if (nodeCopy.classList.contains('insideBox')){
    nodeCopy.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; left:"+ ev.x +"px;top:"+ ev.y+"px;transform:translate(-"+nodeCopy.width/2+"px,-"+nodeCopy.height/2+"px)");
    }
    else{
      nodeCopy=nodeCopy.cloneNode(true)
      nodeCopy.classList.add("insideBox");
      nodeCopy.id = "newId"+Math.random(100);
      nodeCopy.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; left:"+ ev.x +"px;top:"+ ev.y+"px;transform:translate(-"+nodeCopy.width/2+"px,-"+nodeCopy.height/2+"px)");
      ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }

}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}     
.box {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
 <br />
  <div id="picture" ondrop="drop(event)">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
  </div>
```

Comment: I did it in the original snippet but i do not recommend to use it. Just use it as example on how its done

Comment: Drag and drop doesnt work on mobile, you need to use a external library